# Rails nested resources and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, reference, mongoid, relationship

Let's say I have a devise model called "User" which has_many `:notes` and `:notebooks` and each `:notebook` has_many `:notes`.

So a notes will have two foreign key, `:user_id` and `:notebook_id`, so how to build/find a note?

current_user.notebooks.find(param).notes.new(params[:item]) will create the foreign_key only for notebook or also for the user in the note record in the DB?

If the second case (foreign key only for notebook), how should I write?

Using MongoDB with MongoID and referenced relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid will manage the document references and queries for you, just make sure to specify the association/relationship for each direction that you need (e.g., User has_many :notes AND Note belongs_to :user).  Like ActiveRecord, it appears to be "smart" about the relations.  Please do not manipulate the references manually, but instead let your ODM (Mongoid) work for you.  As you run your tests (or use the rails console), you can tail -f log/test.log (or log/development.log) to see what MongoDB operations are being done by Mongoid for you and you can see the actual object references as the documents are updated.  You can see how a relationship makes use of a particular object reference, and if you pay attention to this, the link optimization should become clearer.

The following models and test work for me.  Details on the setup are available on request.  Hope that this helps.

Models

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

  has_many :notebooks
  has_many :notes
end

class Note
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :text

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :notebook
end

class Notebook
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notes
end
```

Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    User.delete_all
    Note.delete_all
    Notebook.delete_all
  end

  test "user" do
    user = User.create!(name: 'Charles Dickens')
    note = Note.create!(text: 'It was the best of times')
    notebook = Notebook.create!(title: 'Revolutionary France')
    user.notes << note
    assert_equal(1, user.notes.count)
    user.notebooks << notebook
    assert_equal(1, user.notebooks.count)
    notebook.notes << note
    assert_equal(1, notebook.notes.count)
    puts "user notes: " + user.notes.inspect
    puts "user notebooks: " + user.notebooks.inspect
    puts "user notebooks notes: " + user.notebooks.collect{|notebook|notebook.notes}.inspect
    puts "note user: " + note.user.inspect
    puts "note notebook: " + note.notebook.inspect
    puts "notebook user: " + notebook.user.inspect
  end

end
```

Result

```
Run options: --name=test_user

# Running tests:

user notes: [#<Note _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000002, _type: nil, text: "It was the best of times", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000001'), notebook_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000003')>]
user notebooks: [#<Notebook _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000003, _type: nil, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000001'), title: "Revolutionary France">]
user notebooks notes: [[#<Note _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000002, _type: nil, text: "It was the best of times", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000001'), notebook_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000003')>]]
note user: #<User _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000001, _type: nil, name: "Charles Dickens">
note notebook: #<Notebook _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000003, _type: nil, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4fa430937f11ba65ce000001'), title: "Revolutionary France">
notebook user: #<User _id: 4fa430937f11ba65ce000001, _type: nil, name: "Charles Dickens">
.

Finished tests in 0.018622s, 53.6999 tests/s, 161.0998 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
class User
  has_many :notebooks
  has_many :notes, :through => :notebooks
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

**Update**

You could always set the user_id manually, like this (I assume param is the ID for your notebook?):

```
Notebook.find(param).notes.new(params[:item].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

Comment: mongoid (odm for mongodb) doesn't support through

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't see that bit about Mongo. Please ignore then.